# How to add regex modifier to Laravel 5.1 route where constraint?

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am trying to add a where constraint to a route like the following:

```
Route::get('{franchise}', ['as' => 'franchise.home', 'uses' => 'FranchiseController@home'])
->where('franchise', 'ford|nissan|mazda|skoda|kia');
```

I want the car manufacturers to be case insensitive, so that it would match FORD, Ford, ford, forD.

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
->where('franchise', 'ford|nissan|mazda|skoda|kia/i');
->where('franchise', '/ford|nissan|mazda|skoda|kia/i');
```

Is it even possible to add regex modifiers to this where constraint on a route?

Comment: Have you tried `->where('franchise', '(?i)ford|nissan|mazda|skoda|kia');` yet?

Comment: Wow that works. Why don't you put it down as an answer?

Comment: Done, just wondered if it will work with `where`, too. With `with`, it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the inline case-insensitive modifier `(?i)` at the start of your pattern so that it could match both lower- and uppercase character variants:

```
->where('franchise', '(?i)ford|nissan|mazda|skoda|kia');
```